# How to show $E[|X|]= \sigma$ where $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

Let $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. I want to show that $$E[|X|]= \sigma.$$

Comment: Look up the "Half-normal" distribution, and this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518281/how-to-derive-the-mean-and-variance-of-a-gaussian-random-variable/519631#519631

Comment: That formula doesn't look right...

Comment: There is no valid demonstration of this equality, because the expectation is $\sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.$  The indefinite integral is simple and can be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: The aim is doomed. The answer is $\sigma\root \of {2/\pi}$. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The straightforward approach to finding the expectation comes from using the continuous version of the law of the unconscious statistician:

$E(g(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) f_X(x) dx$ .

You may find it easier to use $E(|X|) = \sigma\cdot E(|X/\sigma|) =\sigma\cdot E(|Z|)$.

So that leaves you with trying to find:

$E(|Z|) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |z|\, \phi(z)\, dz$

where $\phi(z)$ is the standard normal density.

Then show that (/explain why) the term inside the integral is even.

That means you can write it as $2\int_{0}^{\infty}...$, allowing you to simplify the expression inside the integral, getting rid of the awkward absolute-value function.

Then it's simply a matter of writing $\phi$ out, followed by an obvious substitution, leaving an easy integral, which yields the answer you've already been given a couple of times in comments.

Comment: After "... writing $\Phi$ out," I would have used the phrase "staring very hard at the derivative of $-e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$ to see if inspiration strikes,...."